Glibc lib removed, can't compile nothing. Can I precompile it with liveUSB then cp -r to hard drive?
To order to install needed linuxheaders6.10.0 I have unmet dependencies with >glibc2.38, but Ubuntu Jammy repo have only glibc_2.35.
So, I'd remove whole glibc to build glibc2.41 from debian source file.
NOW Can't  do nothing.
Can I prebuild it on liveUSB same Jammy Ubuntu? What else I can do? (Do not send me answers wipe all ur system it's obvious).
Can I do following?..:
a) simply boot Jammy LiveUSB, then
b) while building 2.41glibc source on liveflash track all compilation/installation changes
$ touch /file
# compile glibc
$ find / -newercm /file

c) simple cp -r all changed compiled  files to my tortured Ubuntu??? Or there will some ldd etc problems???
P.S.
libc fails to build with this error on my PC
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile



Can I do following

Your best bet is to boot from a USB / recovery CD, etc. and copy the GLIBC 2.35 which comes with that distribution to the place you removed it from.
After that, your system should be able to boot and work again.

to install needed linuxheaders6.10.0

You should reconsider the need to install them on the system. Instead use a docker container to do whatever it is you are trying to do -- if you screw that up, recovery would be much easier.

w t f amount of questions u answer, already saw u there not even second time)))))))
